# How do you prepare for AIME?

Tags: contest-math

Is the best way to prepare for AIME with past problems or with books? If with books, could you recommend some?

Comment: not via this website

Comment: I'd say past problems is best though

Comment: Related: http://awesomemathgirls.org/math-competitions/how-to-prepare/. I don't know personally since I didn't take the AIME.

Comment: @mathworker21, are you stating that from personal experience of taking the AIME?

Comment: idk what that means. I did take AIME, but I didn't live two different lives in which one I prepared via past problems and the other I prepared via books and in the first life I did better on the AIME than in the second.

Comment: @mathworker21 what I mean is, if you did well on the AIME, then how did you prepare? With books or with past problems? It doesn't matter if one might be better if you tried one of them and it worked.

Comment: @DavidDong both

Answer (score 2):

You might already know of the Art of Problem Solving website. That's your best resource. If you are asking for AIME preparation, perhaps you are confident with your AMC skills? If not, you need to focus on this test to make sure you can even get to the AIME. Focus on strengthening your weakest subject. In general, the four "competition subjects" are Algebra, Geometry, Number Theory, and Combinatorics. Learn the basics first. I can't speak for all of the AoPS books, but the self-titled ones "Art of Problem Solving Volume 1&2" are very good. They cover all the topics at a very good level for the AIME.

Experience: AMC 12 DHR, 2-time AIME score of 7 (not that great, but...)

Comment: Absolutely! I found AOPS books great for building a foundation. I think that that simply trying out AMC and aime tests gives you an idea of what topics of math you understand and can apply best in contest contexts. then you can try to delve deeper and learn what you already don’t. AMC 12 barely qualified and a 10 on aime. oh and by the way, try not to shy away from topics you don’t understand at all, and ask for help when needed. AIME truly is a test when the problems range from jokes to seemingly impossible